# Use Runkit_Sandbox in lampp

Tags: php, lampp, runkit

I want to use the sandboxing of the extension `runkit`. From `README` file

```
Sandboxing is ONLY AVAILABLE in PHP 5.1 (release version, or snapshot dated
after April 28th, 2005) when thread safety has been enabled.
```

The version of PHP in my lampp is 5.4.7 which should be OK but its `Thread Safety` is disabled. From `phpinfo()` we can see the `runkit` is installed but its `Sandbox Support` is disabled or unavailable. So when I try to use the `Runkit_Sandbox` class, an error came out

```
Fatal error: Class 'Runkit_Sandbox' not found
```

I don't really what to do now.. Is it possible to use `Runkit_Sandbox` class in my lampp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master branch of http://github.com/zenovich/runkit is compatible with all versions of PHP. Sandboxing only works if thread safety is enabled. So you should recompile your PHP after configuring it with flag --enable-maintainer-zts to use Runkit_Sandbox class. After that you should use Runkit compiled from source.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention and sorry for not seeing your answer till now.. I will try your solution and thanks again.